# Sub domains on the fly or Wild Card subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wildcard-subdomain

Is it possible to redirect everything in a subdomain to the main domain.

Eg

anything.example.com

something.anything.example.com

must all go to example.com

and

anything.example.com/page.php

something.anything.example.com/page.php

must all go to example.com/page.php

is this possible ? on a shared host ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yah, sure that's possible. just set up a subdomain that's a wildcard (* on most apaches) and set the VH to be the site root.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you have access to the DNS records.
You have to add an A-record, with as values * and the ip of example.com